# Why a Character arrayList contents is different from a char array?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I found a problem when trying to copy contents from a `ArrayList<Character>` to a char array:

```
ArrayList<Character> temp = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if (string[i] != ' ') {  
        temp.add(string[i]);
    } else {
        temp.add('%');
        temp.add('2');
    }
}
string = temp.toArray(string);
```

I guess the problem happens because `ArrayList` is a list of `Character` objects but the array is `char[]`.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What problem are you having? Don't you think it makes sense to explain your problem rather than just dump code and complain about some other question you asked?

Comment: What is the variable "string" used inside for loop?

Comment: Why are you even using an `ArrayList<Character>`? If you want a mutable string, use a [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html), and then use `sb.toString().toCharArray()` to convert it to a `char[]` (If your variable is named `sb`)

Comment: The correct encoding for a space is `%20` (not `%2`), you should probably just use [`URLEncoder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this

```
    ArrayList<Character> temp = ...

    String string=temp.stream().map(c->c.toString()).collect(Collectors.joining(""));

    char[] charArray=string.toCharArray();

    System.out.println(charArray);
```